# How to fix setState after disposeError on a screen with a tabBar

Tags: dart, flutter

So in my app, I have a screen with a `tabBar`. When the screen loads, it sorts out the items and moves them into different tabs. But when I run this, The Items keep duplicating, and I am shown an error in the debug console that says I called `setState()` after `dispose()`

Here's the code for the screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
import './uiComponents/customWidgets.dart';
import './ticketsComponents/ticketsList.dart';
import './tabs.dart';    

class Tickets extends StatefulWidget {
  Tickets({ this.tickets, this.user });
  final List tickets;
  final Map user;

  @override
  _TicketsState createState() => new _TicketsState();
}

class _TicketsState extends State<Tickets> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller; // Tab controller for the screen    
  List _tickets;

  // Variables to Store the sorted Tickets
  List _availableTickets = [];
  List _usedTickets = [];
  List _expiredTickets = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    controller = new TabController(
      vsync: this, 
      length: 4, 
      initialIndex: 1
    );

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPersistentFrameCallback((_) async {

      // Get the tickets and sort them
      _tickets = widget.tickets;
      if(_tickets != null){
        _sortTickets();
      }
    });    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //  DELETE A TICKET (FROM ID)
  void deleteTicket(int id){
    setState(() {
      _tickets.removeWhere((item)=> item["id"] == id);
      _availableTickets = [];
      _usedTickets = [];
      _expiredTickets = [];

      _sortTickets();
    });
  }

  //  SORT THE TICKETS INTO AVAILABLE / UNUSED, USED AND EXPIRED
  void _sortTickets(){
    for (int i = 0; i < _tickets.length; i++){      
      Map ticket  = _tickets[i];

      if(ticket["isUsed"]){
        setState(() {
          _usedTickets.add(ticket);            
        });
      }
      else if(ticket["expired"]){
        setState(() {
          _expiredTickets.add(ticket);            
        });
      }
      else{
        setState(() {
          _availableTickets.add(ticket);            
        });
      }
    }
  }

  //  NAVIGATE TO MAIN TAB AND CLEAR PREVIOUS ROUTES 
  void _navProfile(){
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Tabs(
          user: widget.user
        )
      ),
      (route)=> false
    );
  }    

  //  TabBar for Filtering Tickets
  TabBar _buildTabBar(){
    return new TabBar(
      controller: controller,
      indicatorWeight:2.2,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize:14.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
      ),
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontWeight:FontWeight.normal
      ),
      labelColor: blue,
      indicatorColor: blue,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: "All"),
        Tab(text: "Available"),
        Tab(text: "Used"),
        Tab(text: "Expired")
      ],
    );
  }

  //  THE AppBar with the sub menu under it
  AppBar _buildAppBar(){
    Function onBackButtonPressed = _navProfile;    
    return new AppBar(
      title: customTextBold("My Tickets"),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(
        color: blue
      ),
      leading: GestureDetector(
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: blue),
        onTap: onBackButtonPressed,
      ),
      elevation: 1.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottom: _buildTabBar()
    );
  }

  //  BUILD MAIN SCREEN
  Container _buildTicketsPage(){
    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundBlue
      ),
      child: new TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          TicketsList(
            tickets: _tickets,
            deleteTicket: deleteTicket,
          ),

          TicketsList(
            tickets: _availableTickets,
            deleteTicket: deleteTicket,
          ),

          TicketsList(
            tickets: _usedTickets,
            deleteTicket: deleteTicket,
          ),

          TicketsList(
            tickets: _expiredTickets,
            deleteTicket: deleteTicket,
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  //  UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: (_tickets == null)
      ? buildLoadingScreen("Fetching Tickets")
      : _buildTicketsPage()
    );
  }
}
```

Running this will render the correct screen, but the ticket items will start duplicating, and this error is displayed on the debug console:

```
.
E/flutter (31673): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _TicketsState#2cafe(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted, ticker inactive)
E/flutter (31673): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the t
```

Please how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

add before each `setState` a condition

```
if(!mounted) return;
```

for example:

```
if(!mounted) return;
setState(() {
 _expiredTickets.add(ticket);            
});
```

Comment: do you mean that setState is called even if not mounted, can you please add your code?